# Constraints related issue in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, scipy, minimize

I've got a function `g` which I'm minimizing over an array `coeffs` subject to a list of constraints `cons`.

If I use

```
n = 2 
cons2 = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda cts: 1 - sabs(apNn(n,n,np.roll(cts, - 0 * 2**(n + 1))))},
            {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda cts: 1 - sabs(apNn(n,n,np.roll(cts, - 1 * 2**(n + 1))))}]
ans = scipy.optimize.minimize(g, coeffs, constraints=cons2)
```

then everything works fine. (`sabs` and `apNn` are functions I've defined previously.).

However if I generate the constraints in a loop and use:

```
cons = []
for v in range(2):
    cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda cts: 1 - sabs(apNn(n,n,np.roll(cts, - v * 2**(n + 1))))})
ans = scipy.optimize.minimize(g, coeffs, constraints=cons)
```

then the optimization fails with message `Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem`. Given that the for loop  is generating exactly the same thing I can't see where this difference is coming from.

Comment: "Given that the for loop is generating exactly the same thing": it isn't, though-- the value of `v` is only looked up when the function is called. The answer to the linked question explains what's going on and the usual workarounds.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Would never have got that on my own.